# Failed to specialize function template in threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to implement a Thread in c++ wich it will be used to control when I take a picture, but this simple code is giving me a strange error, which I can't understand. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
    using namespace std;

    void counter(int seconds, bool &flagTakePhoto, bool &flagThreadStart);

int main() {
    bool takePhoto, threadStart;

    int seconds = 1;

    thread t(counter, seconds, takePhoto, threadStart);
    //Some code here
}


void counter(int seconds, bool &flagTakePhoto, bool &flagThreadStart) {
    while (flagThreadStart) {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(seconds));
        flagTakePhoto = true;
    }
    terminate();
}
```

This is the error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Proyecto para pruebas OPENCV, Configuration: 
Release x64 ------
1>  Main.cpp
1>Main.cpp(46): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from '__int64' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thr/xthread(238): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thr/xthread(238): note: With the following template arguments:
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thr/xthread(238): note: '_Callable=void (__cdecl *)(int,bool &,bool &)'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thr/xthread(238): note: '_Types={int, bool, bool}'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thr/xthread(247): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Execute<0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03>(std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(int,bool &,bool &),int,bool,bool> &,std::integer_sequence<_Ty,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03>)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(int,bool &,bool &),int,bool,bool>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(int,bool &,bool &),int,bool,bool>>>,
1>              _Ty=size_t
1>          ]
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thr/xthread(247): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Execute<0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03>(std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(int,bool &,bool &),int,bool,bool> &,std::integer_sequence<_Ty,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03>)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(int,bool &,bool &),int,bool,bool>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(int,bool &,bool &),int,bool,bool>>>,
1>              _Ty=size_t
1>          ]
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thr/xthread(242): note: while compiling class template member function 'void std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<_Target> *) noexcept'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(int,bool &,bool &),int,bool,bool>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(int,bool &,bool &),int,bool,bool>>>
1>          ]
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thr/xthread(230): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<_Target> *) noexcept' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(int,bool &,bool &),int,bool,bool>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(int,bool &,bool &),int,bool,bool>>>
1>          ]
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thr/xthread(256): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_LaunchPad<_Target>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(int,bool &,bool &),int,bool,bool>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(int,bool &,bool &),int,bool,bool>>>
1>          ]
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thread(52): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Launch<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(int,bool &,bool &),int,bool,bool>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(int,bool &,bool &),int,bool,bool>>>>(_Thrd_t *,_Target &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(int,bool &,bool &),int,bool,bool>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl *)(int,bool &,bool &),int,bool,bool>>>
1>          ]
1>  Main.cpp(136): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::thread::thread<void(__cdecl &)(int,bool &,bool &),int&,bool&,bool&,void>(_Fn,int &,bool &,bool &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fn=void (__cdecl &)(int,bool &,bool &)
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What is more strange about this is that I have a similar code in other program and compile with no errors!
Does anyone knows what's wrong with this code?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure it's the reference binding. Can't do that.

Comment: `thread t(counter, seconds, std::ref(takePhoto), std::ref(threadStart));`. also, you should initialize the boolean variables before reading their values (at least `threadStart`)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki yes I have them initialized in my code, I just forget to put on my question. Also your answer worked for me. Thanks!
If you write that as an answer I'll mark it

Comment: http://ideone.com/0a0HRY working with reference wrappers created by `std::ref`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`std::thread` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) will construct all of its objects and call the function as if by:

```
template <class T>
typename decay<T>::type decay_copy(T&& v) {
    return std::forward<T>(v);
}
```

That makes the argument types of

```
thread t(counter, seconds, takePhoto, threadStart);
```

be `int`, `bool`, `bool`. Since you cannot call `counter(int, bool, bool)` (it takes lvalue references), that constructor is ill-formed.

In order to pass references, you need to wrap your arguments in [`std::reference_wrapper<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper). That type is implicitly convertible to `T&`, so calling `counter(int, std::reference_wrapper<bool>, std::reference_wrapper<bool>)` is valid. For short-hand, the standard provides [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref), so you can just do the following:

```
thread t(counter, seconds, std::ref(takePhoto), std::ref(threadStart));
```